# SSH server listening on 0.0.0.0:22?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I have two machines in my home network and I want to connect them over SSH. The first machine has a local ip `192.168.1.23` and *openssh remote client* installed. The second has a local ip  `192.168.1.169` and *openssh server* installed.

I start the service in the second machine,

```
sudo systemctl start ssh
```

and then I go to the client machine and fail to connect with,

```
ssh myusername@192.168.1.169:22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname 0.0.0.0:22: Name or service not known
```

After the above failure I went back to the server machine and checked out the `ssh` service status which says that *the server is listening on 0.0.0.0:22*.

1. Is that (0.0.0.0:22) ok?
2. How can I establish that connection over SSH?
3. Are `ssh` and `sshd` the same service?

Comment: `ssh` is a protocol for secure communication over an insecure network while `sshd` provides a daemon which responds to incoming SSH requests. Also, when you specify a port using `ssh` use the `-p` flag. So, `ssh -p22 user@ipaddress` NOT `ssh user@ipaddress:22`

Comment: I'm trying to connect like that but I get `myusername@0.0.0.0: Permission denied (publickey, password)`. Any thoughts @ldias ?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is just shorthand for "all IPv4 interfaces" - it's not a real address that you should use in the ssh command

Comment: Wow thanks @steeldriver, at last I am connected (`ssh -p22 myusername@192.168.1.169`)

Comment: @Themelis Is your problem solved then?

Comment: It's solved @ldias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SSH` is a protocol for secure communication over an insecure network while `sshd` provides a daemon which responds to incoming SSH requests.

When you specify a port in `ssh` use the `-p` flag. So, for example:

```
ssh -p22 user@ipaddress
```

**NOT**

```
ssh user@ipaddress:22
```

Your IP address would be something like `192.168.x.x` not `0.0.0.0` As @steeldriver pointed out in the comments, "`0.0.0.0` is just shorthand for 'all IPv4 interfaces'. It's not a real address that you should use in a ssh command".